# Mongoose schema method not working after select paramter

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose model with a method that checks a field and dynamically returns a value, and is called in an HTML template.

This gave me a problem when cleaning up routes to only select fields needed on the page.

After including the select parameter as in `Model.find({}, 'select parameter', cb...`, this schema method started failing, despite including in the select parameter the property this schema method checks.

Whats up with this, is there a way around it?

The schema method is defined inside `thingSchema.methods: { ... ...`

and looks for `this.thing.length`

which is included in the select parameter `'thing, otherThing, thingyThing, thingestThing'`

and is called in the html template like `thing.getThing()`, which will throw error can't find prop length of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a problem with the string type for the select parameter.

Use the object type instead: `{thing:1,otherThing:1,things:1}`.